# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.ANTLRException

Tags: java, antlr

I have a method to get first result of a table.

```
public T LoadFirstData()
{
    T object = null;
    try {
        startOperation();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from " + type.getName());
        object = (T) query.list().get(0);
    } 
    catch (HibernateException e) 
    {
        HandleException(e);
    } finally 
    {
        HibernateUtil.Close(session);
    }
    return object;
}
```

But, when I run the method, I have the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/ANTLRException
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
    at DataAccess.WKS.Repositories.WksRepositoryBase.LoadAllData(WksRepositoryBase.java:193)
    at Run.main(Run.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.ANTLRException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

I have searched on the web for the solution, all I found was missing antlr jar. But I have already added the jar into my project.

list of jars:

```
ant-antlr.jar
antlr-4.2.2.jar
antlr-runtime-4.2.2.jar
asm-attrs.jar
asm.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-3.1.jar
hibernate3-client.jar
hibernate3.jar
javassist.jar
jboss-client.jar
jta.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
ojdbc14-jdbc4.jar
ojdbc14.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
```

Can I know what else I have missed?

Comment: It's not in the runtime CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the wrong antlr in your project.

The one you need is this. I hope it helps :)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I also see that you are using a older version of hibernate.  Latest one available is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

[Download latest hibernate jars](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.5.Final)

Comment: Ok now based on that question I think you are not using maven. Is that correct? Are straight copying the jars from internet in your lib folder?

Comment: Just added links for your ease in the answer. You can download the jars from the links.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Still in study mode, because just switch from C# to JAVA..And I found the error when debugging..How to add this in debug mode?

Comment: There is no difference in java like adding a jar to debug mode etc. If you add it it's available in debug as well as run mode.

Comment: Thanks. hmmm, my jars were wrong...Thanks for reminding.